# How to created stacked view pager

Tags: android, stack, android-viewpager, swipe

How to make the view pager to show the next page above the previous one, not on the next (arrange the views as stack not besides each other)

Comment: Do you mean that you want the pages to swipe vertically, instead of horizontally?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, but also when the page transforms it appears above the the precious one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical ViewPager implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889530/vertical-viewpager-implementation)

Comment: when swipe I don't the previous page to move, I need it to stay and the current page to come over it

Comment: There is a library JazzyViewPager. https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager. This provides numerous animations for ViewPager. One of the animations in "Stack". If you only wish to achieve such animating effect, then this library can help.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` does not offer this. You will need to write your own `ViewGroup` that implements what you want. You might look at the implementation of `ViewPager` to learn some techniques that can be applied in your case, or even look to fork `ViewPager` to add your desired features to it.